# Google Maps Infowindow not showing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I've got google maps in my application. Everything is working as it should, except for one problem. My pins shows as a bubble (name of technician), which is working. But if I click on this technician (pin) it should open an infowindow that displays more information regarding the technician for example amount of calls, distance to client, ect... (the data is being pulled through), the only problem that I'm facing is that the info window is not showing at all when I click on the pin/technician... I've gone through the code but can't seem to find where I went wrong with this...

This is my javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var marker = $("#<%= txtTechnicians.ClientID %>").val();
        var markers = JSON.parse(marker);

        var markerCustomer = $("#<%= txtCustomer.ClientID %>").val();
        var markerCust = JSON.parse(markerCustomer);

        function initialize() {

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markerCust[0].lat, markerCust[0].lng),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions:
                   {
                       style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                       poistion: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
                       mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                         google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                         google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                         google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE]
                   },
                streetViewControl: true,
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions:
                {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                },
                scaleControl: true,
                draggableCursor: 'move'
            });

            var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
            trafficLayer.setMap(map);

            var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#FF8200' });
            poly.setMap(map);

            var lat_lngCust = new Array();
            for (i = 0; i < markerCust.length; i++) {
                var data = markerCust[i]
                var myLatlngCust = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); lat_lngCust.push(myLatlngCust);
                var markerCustomer = new StyledMarker({
                    styleIcon: new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.BUBBLE, { color: "#D20202", text: data.title }),
                    position: myLatlngCust, map: map, title: data.title
                });

                (function (markerCustomer, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCustomer, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, markerCustomer);
                    });
                })(markerCustomer, data);
            }

            var lat_lng = new Array();
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
                var marker = new StyledMarker({
                styleIcon: new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.BUBBLE, { color: data.colourcode, text: data.title }),
                    position: myLatlng, map: map, title: data.title
                });

                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your attached code, `infoWindow` is not defined anywhere.

I think you are just missing this line;
`var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();`

**See below:**

```
(function (marker, data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description); // @SEE: infoWindow is used but not initialized or declare anywhere within the scope.
        infoWindow.open(map, marker); // same
    });
})(marker, data);
```